# Angular material datepicker service

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular6

Im using this angular material libary:

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

and im trying to use the Service MatDatepickerIntl they suggested.

datepicker.component.html:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker"  placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker  #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

datepicker.component.ts

```
  constructor(public datePicker: MatDatepickerIntl) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.datePicker.changes
      .subscribe(ch => {
        console.log(ch);
      })
  }
```

but its dosent seems to catch changes in the datepicker label.
do i need to attach the service to my mat-datepicker selector and how?

Comment: did you add MatDatepickerModule in app.module.ts ?

Comment: Yes and MatNativeDateModule also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import MatDatepickerModule in app.module.ts file

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
.
.
.
.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    .
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    .
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

might be helpful for someone who is looking to accomplish this after all this time (like me). one way would be to implement your own. i've tried it with the selection model. might give you some hint on how to implement to what you need.

```
    export class MySelectionModel<D> extends MatRangeDateSelectionModel<D> {
        isComplete(): boolean {
               // your implementation here.
        }
    }

    @Component({
      providers: [
        {
           provide: MatDateSelectionModel,
           useClass: MySelectionModel
        }
```